# Synchronizing Fusion Tables

Tags: google-sheets, google-fusion-tables, google-forms

I am a high school student who has taken a course this year on app inventing. We recently started a project where we are making apps that would benefit our school in a positive way. We decided we would make a website for our app for those that can't access the app. We came to a roadblock and asked our teacher to help us out. Unfortunately, he wasn't able to provide us with the help we needed. So he said to find something online that can help us, which is why I have come here.

Our app project was for a place where people can report found items, or look for any item they lost. On our website, we created a Google Form for them to fill out, which then gets inserted into a Google Spreadsheet. From the spreadsheet, we were trying to get the information to be transferred over to a Google Fusion Table which we found a site that has a step by step explanation on how to do so. This is where we have come across our error. We're not sure why this keeps happening, and have triple checked everything and nothing has fixed this error. We were hoping someone could help us out and provide any sort of assistance on fixing this error.

Attached is the screenshot of the error we keep receiving, and the link to the website we used to help transfer the information.

[Synchronizing Fusion Tables!](http://fusion-tables-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/FusionTablesFormSync/docs/reference.html)

Thank you for your time, and hope to hear back from you soon.

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer as we have little information. Someone had the same problem and had in fact not switched the service on in the script editor, so in case you wouldn't have come across the link: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-fusion-tables/6ZtaoDUASb4/M5iqO6-6dOQJ